# Is it possible to change orientation with a button event but disable auto rotate?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I use codes below to change orientation of a view controller:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft] forKey:@"orientation"];
```

It can force orientation to landscape, but I can not make it work with disabling auto rotate:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}
```

Is this possible to change orientation with a button event but disable auto rotate?

Comment: what is the use case of disabling auto rotate

Answer (score 0):

Declare a boolean variable check  and then on the basis of the value you can enable or disable orientaion.

```
   - (IBAction)someButton:(id)sender {
       [self changeOrientation];
            }

    -(void)changeOrientation
    {
        check = true;
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft] forKey:@"orientation"];

    }

    -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
        if (check) {
            return YES;
            check = false;

        }
        return NO;
    }
```

Comment: When in portrait, hit button to change to landscape
When in landscape, hit button change to portrait
So can not just use a variable check to enable/disable orientation